# LyX error - 'Document format failure' for file in temporary folder

Tags: lyx

I have been working during the last year in my thesis with LyX. Yesterday I opened my file in another computer and when I open it in mine this error appears:

[image]

What can I do to solve this issue?

Thank you very much in advance. It is very urgent because I will submit my thesis in a few weeks.

Greetings

Comment: Have you tried opening the document with a plain tex editor?  If it looks fine there, you can try re-saving it and then opening it with Lyx.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Looks to be a temporary file that is corrupted, but safety first, so do you have backups of your thesis? (You should.) Moving on, does it still open in the other computer? Does that computer also have LyX 2.0.x, or does it use LyX 2.1? If you open the `.lyx` file in a text editor one of the first lines will tell you which version of LyX created the file.

Comment: You might have run into a nasty LyX bug: http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/9049 However I notice that you're using 2.0.6. It could also be a lyx2lyx issue if the other computer you used has LyX 2.1. Please upgrade LyX to 2.1 and try to open the file again.

Comment: Note: If by any chance for any reason you do *not* have a backup of the file, make a copy of the file *before* you do anything else. Before you try opening it in anything at all. Only work with the copy you make. However, you surely have backups of your thesis, right? (Not only you should have backups - you should make sure other people have backups, too e.g. leave one with your advisor or send one to your grandmother or whatever.)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. The file was made with LyX 2.1 and I was trying to open it with LyX 2.0. Updating my version of LyX solved the problem.