# Document Format Failure

Tags: lyx

I made a lyx document but when I send this document to my instructor's system, it gives the following error
[image]

Kindly help, what sort of issue is this?

Comment: I notice that the error comes from your `Temp` directory.  Try naming, renaming, or re-creating the document in a regular directory, that might help. Use a name that is something short, for instance `mydoc.lyx` would work.

Comment: What's his and what's your LyX version?  If the versions don't match LyX starts conversion. That however sometimes doesn't work, especially if you have a lot of raw TeX code included.Send your instructor a very simple document and see if that works. If your LyX version is newer, try exporting in an older document format.

Comment: In addition to the above comment, LyX developers would love to see the file that does not open. Can you send the file to lyx-devel@lists.lyx.org ? This way if there is a bug we can fix it. Note that it is a public mailing list so please remove anything you do not want public.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180664/lyx-error-document-format-failure-for-file-in-temporary-folder